# Runtime error = '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, runtime-error

I'm trying to write to a program that will indicate an alphabet grade to each student in accord with their marks. Basically, the indicated grade will be shown in column C. From the data table, John will receive a grade "A" as his mark is higher than or equal to 85. Plus, the cell of his grade will be filled green and center aligned. However, for students whose mark is lower than 35, the students will receive a grade "F" in column C. Moreover, the whole row(Column A,B,C) of that student will be filled red. When I try to run the program, I get a

> run time error = '1004'.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

**Also is my method of counting the row and column with data right?

[image: Data]

```
    Sub Green()


       Dim Mark As Integer
       Dim c As Integer
       Dim r As Integer
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim j As Integer



      r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
      c = (Selection.End(xlToRight).row) / r

          For i = 0 To r

             For j = 0 To c

                Mark = Range(i, "B").Value

                  If Mark >= 85 And Mark <= 100 Then

                        Range(i, "C").Value = "A"
                        Range(i, "C").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                        Range(i, "C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

                   ElseIf Mark >= 0 And Mark <= 35 Then

                        Range(i, "C").Value = "F"
                        Range(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        Range(i, "C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

                   Else


                End If

         Next j

      Next i


                MsgBox ("Rows = " & r)
                MsgBox ("Columns =" & c)



     End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't `.row` in `c = (Selection.End(xlToRight).row) / r` be `.column`? Further, why are you relying on `Selection` and what code line is producing the error?

Comment: Declaring your variables as long `c r i j`

Comment: @Jeep Yes, it's the counting for column. But I don't know why the output for the number of columns shows 8 when only column A and B are used. The error states "Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: `c = cells(columns.count, r).End(xlToLeftt).column` and start using a properly referenced parent worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that you handle conditional formatting to the application's built-in features. If you disagree, feel free to modify this code.

```
Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
    End With
End Function

Sub assignLetterGrade()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, ltr As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    For i = 1 To LastRow(ws, "B")
        Select Case ws.Cells(i, "B")
            Case 85 To 100
                ltr = "A"
            Case 75 To 84
                ltr = "B"
            Case 65 To 74
                ltr = "C"
            Case 55 To 64
                ltr = "D"
            Case 0 To 54
                ltr = "F"
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Unknown Grade! Aborting!"
                Exit Sub
        End Select
        ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = ltr
    Next

End Sub
```

For conditional Formatting, you could try these steps:

1. Select the entire column of which you plan to format conditionally
   (in my example, it's column C.

> [image]

2. Let's create a new rule.

> [image]

3. Now enter your Rules, one at a time. In this example, I am highlighting all cells containing "A" in green.

> [image]

The question remains. Why not format within VBA?

The first thing you should understand about VBA is that it's very inefficient. While minimal code can take fractions of a second, once your loops get larger and larger the more you will notice that it takes longer to complete its task.

Also, you run into issues where your code is not pristine and may have minor errors. Minor errors can turn into major errors when you start building your project (example: using `ActiveSheet` comes to mind. It might work for your small project, but next thing you know you are applying formats to the wrong sheet, referencing the wrong cell's value, so on and so forth).

If you can avoid VBA, then do it. Take advantage of Microsoft's excellent conditional formatting UI. It's very efficient and much easier to manage.

***Also, again this entire VBA project could have been done without using VBA at all. VBA is slow. You could have just as easily used formulas in column C to provide you with the letter grade.***

A less-advanced version of a formula is to use nested If Statements.

```
=IF(B1>=85,"A", IF(B1>=75,"B", IF(B1>=65,"C", IF(B1>=55,"D","F"))))
```